# How can I define a relationship in rails so that a model can have varying types of associated models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, model-associations

I don't know the correct database terminology to explain what I'm asking so I'll do my best to explain it.

I have an invoice model which has_one invoicee.

The invoicee can either be an internal department or an external department.

I can set this up with an invoicee table that has the columns for either which feels messy (it'll leave a lot of nil columns).

I can set up an internal_invoicee and external_invoicee table and only create one as needed which seems better but I then have to manage 2 different associations.

I could then set up an invoicee method in my invoice model that returns either the internal or external invoicee depending on which one exists and manage the business logic so that only one ever exists.

This second solution seems like the better way of doing it but it still feels messy to me. Is there a built in way of doing this in Rails? It feels like a polymorphic association only in reverse.

I've never looked at NoSQL databases, but is this the sort of thing that they do well?

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to have many more departments than just internal or external? Or do you need cascading updates to a separate department table?

If not, add boolean department_type column to invoicee table. No relationship required.

If so, write a method in your invoicee model to determine the department type with a foreign key. Add department_id and invoice_id columns to invoicee and an invoicee_id column on invoice.

Use `has_one :department` and `has_many :invoices` on invoicee, `has_many :invoices` on departments, and `belongs_to :invoicee` on invoices.

Side note: Can you pick a better name than invoicee? It's too confusingly close to invoice!